# Как изменить значение в куче клонов префаба?

Tags: unity3d

Делаю игру на подобие Craft the World. Есть карта ресурсов. Каждый уникальный ресурс имеет префаб. При заполнении карты я просто создаю клоны префаба нужного ресурса. У каждого префаба есть скрипт `Resource`. В этом скрипте есть много значений, таких как: `cost`, `name`, `description`, `hardness`, `isTaked` и т.д. Также есть значение `isKnown`. То есть, знает ли игрок что-то об этом ресурсе. Игрок, добывший неизвестный ресурс, должен закинуть его в лабораторию для его изучения. После этого он уже знает о нём всё (`isKnown = true`). Ему доступны уже другие значения (`name`, `description` и т.д.). Но значение я поменял только в текущем клоне и это я понимаю.

Чтобы поменять это самое значение (isKnown) в других клонах данного ресурса на карте мне нужно будет перелопатить 2000+ объектов и в нужных заменить значение с `isKnown = false` на `isKnown = true`. Как по мне это далеко не самое правильное решение. Возможно, я изначально подошел к этому вопросу неправильно. Как мне изменять значение одного типа ресурса по ходу игры и при этом другие клоны этого же типа ресурсы знали об этом изменении? Я думал по поводу делегатов и ивентов. Но я не знаю как правильно реализовать через них.

Comment: Как вариант можно может попробовать через теги?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам вопрос "Как изменить одно и то-же поле на одно и то-же значение у множества объектов" намекает на то, что это поле описывает не конкретную единицу а сразу все множество и должно быть в единственном месте.

Вам нужен объект описывающий каждый тип ресурса. Но изменяемые и не изменяемые значения всегда хранят в разных моделях. Для константных данных прекрасно подойдет `ScriptableObject`.

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "ResourceConstance", menuName = "Resource/Constance")]
public class ResourceConstance : ScriptableObject
{
    public ResourceType Type;
    public string Name;
    public string Description;
    public int BaseCost;
    public int BaseHardness;
}
```

Полная информация о ресурсах состоит и констант и значений.

```
[Serializable]
public class ResourceValues
{
    public ResourceType Type;
    public bool IsExplored;
    public int BonusLevel;
    public float BoostFactor;

    public ResourceValues (ResourceType type)
    {
        Type = type;
    }
}
```

---

```
public struct ResourceData 
{
    public readonly ResourceConstance Constance;
    public ResourceValues Values;

    public ResourceData (ResourceConstance constance, ResourceValues values)
    {
        Constance = constance;
        Values = values;
    }
}
```

Ну и массив ресурсов тоже `ScriptableObject`

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "ResourceCollection", menuName = "Resource/Collection")]
public class ResourceDataCollection : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] private ResourceConstance[] _constances;
}
```

`ResourceCollection` можно использовать не только как контейнер, но и фасад общей точки доступа данных по ресурсов.

То-есть есть метод `Initialize` который кто-то в начале сцены один раз запускает и он либо грузит данные ли создает свежие.

```
public class ResourceDataCollection : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] private string _key = "ResourcesData";
    [SerializeField] private ResourceConstance[] _constances;

    public Dictionary<ResourceType, ResourceData> Resources;

    public void Initialize ()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey(_key))
            Load();
        else
            Default();
    }

    public void Save ()
    {
        ResourceValues[] values = Resources.Select(r => r.Value.Values).ToArray();
        ValuesSaveCollection save = new ValuesSaveCollection(values);
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(values);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(_key, json);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    private void Load ()
    {
        Resources = new Dictionary<ResourceType, ResourceData>();
        string json = PlayerPrefs.GetString(_key);
        ValuesSaveCollection save = JsonUtility.FromJson<ValuesSaveCollection>(json);
        // сопастовляем каждый values.Type с элементами _constances и собираем Resources
        // для ресурсов из _constances которые не были использованы создаем свежие записи
    }

    [ContextMenu("ClearData")]
    private void Default ()
    {
        Resources = new Dictionary<ResourceType, ResourceData>();
        foreach (var constance in _constances)
            Resources.Add(constance.Type, new ResourceData(constance, new ResourceValues(constance.Type)));
        Save();
    }

    [Serializable]
    private struct ValuesSaveCollection
    {
        public ResourceValues[] Values;

        public ValuesSaveCollection (ResourceValues[] values)
        {
            Values = values;
        }
    }
}
```

Можно сделать более закрытую и защищенную (скорее нужно) с методами изменения, автоматически сохраняющие их, добавить эвенты оповещения и т.д.

Comment: примерно на 20-25% я понял твой совет. И примерно понимаю как мне переделать его для своих целей. В ResourceConstance я могу добавить Image и таким образом я заменю префаб. Круто что изменяемые данные можно было сделать в другом классе под одним типом ресурса(сам блин чёт не додумался) и соединить их в ResourceData. Этот момент я понял. Но есть вопросы. 1) От я создал 2000+ gameObject-тов(Ресурсов), что в объекте должно быть(ResourceConstance который я создал через CreateAssetMenu)? 2) Также я примерно понял по загрузке и сохранении, но как я изменю IsKnown на  true в лаборатории?

Comment: продолжение. Как одно значение поменянное в лаборатории повлияет на ресурсы того же типа ещё не добытые? Где я буду заполнять ResourceValues, отдельный скрипт для заполнение дефолтных значений?

Comment: Мой вариант. Смотри или же читай. Отдельный файл для сохранения данных о ресурсе( как константные данные так и изменяемые). Константные(ResourceConstance ) и изменяемые(ResourceValues) данные записываются в разные temp lists. В gameObject входят константные данные которые берутся по типу с temp list-а. При добыче, когда игрок хочет посмотреть на ресурс который он добыл идёт проверка по типу ресурса в temp list(где хранится IsKnown) если IsKnown - false, то выдаёт unknown resource. Когда игрок исследовал ресурс то значение в temp list(по типу меняется). А при сохранение temp lists читаются.Как?

Comment: помоги плиз разобраться с этими вопросами. Это очень важный кусок коду.

Comment: Давай все ссылка ну на коллекцию, ресурсы сами разберутся какие данные ему брать зная свой `ResourceType`. Данные в коллекции единые для всех. Лаборатория не работает с своими данными, она посредник для работы с коллекцией.

Comment: Ок, примерно я понимаю как собрать мне то что нужно. Я отпишу когда запилю тестовый вариант.

Comment: В общем, сделал как мне нужно. Не уверен что структура моего кода вызывает бабочек в животе по кд, но он работает. Ставлю ответ тебе, так как я использовал твой вариант. Другим кто помогал +.

Answer (score 2):

Простой и рабочий вариант, - использовать статику

Заведите статичное (общее для всего класса) поле `static public bool isKnown {get; set}`

Более правильное решение, которое обеспечит больше гибкости в будущем и некоторую страховку от ошибок, - хранить информацию о изученности отдельно от ресурсов, где-нибудь в статичном классе `GameContext`

Если решите идти по этому пути, то класс предстоит написать самому, но вот несколько советов:

1. Стоит запретить опускать флаг изученности, то есть у вас будет

а) Публичный метод, что бы узнать об изученности ресурса

б) Публичный метод, что бы сделать не изученный ресурс изученным

Не должно быть способа сделать изученный ресурс не изученным, что бы защититься от случайных косяков, в таком случаи статику вполне можно использовать без особых вредных последствий

```
    static private bool _value = false; 

    static public bool Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            if (!_value)
            {
                _value = value;
            }
            else
            {
               //действие при попытке отменить изученность, например, можно кинуть исключение
            }
        }
    }
```

2. Стоит завести `Enum` по типам ресурсов и везде оперировать им, тогда в статичном контексте у вас будет два всего публичных метода, даже для кучи ресурсов:

а) Публичный метод, что бы узнать об изученности ресурса по enumу

б) Публичный метод, что бы сделать не изученный ресурс изученным по enumу

Примечание: используйте статику с умом. Её использование увеличивает связанность кода и затрудняет тестирование

Comment: Если я не буду менять флаг, то как при следующем запуске я буду знать что этот ресурс изучен?

Comment: Нельзя опускать уже поднятый флаг
Поднимать можно, в том числе при загрузке игры

Comment: `Не должно быть способа сделать не изученный ресурс изученным` - наверно вы имели в виду обратное. Уже изученный ресурс нельзя сбросить до неизвестного, так?

Comment: @JuniorOne При вы ходе из игры, а лучше каждые X секунд, а еще лучше (так как изучение нового ресурса не является частым событием) можно сохранять "изученность" ресурсов в PlayerPrefs или через json, как угодно. При загрузке игры загружать данные и ставить изученными те ресурсы, которые были изучены при выходе из игры.

Comment: @МаксимФисман, ок. Я думал по поводу доп файла для "изученность" ресурсов. Это да, он будет подтягивать значение ресурсов. Но, я подымаю флаг у одного gameObject-а(Ресурса), как другие такие же ресурсы узнают что они уже изучены. Как поднять флаг у всех ресурсах одного типу не перезагружая сцену?

Comment: @МаксимаФрисман да, вы правы: опечатался

Comment: @SergeySkvortsov, если я сделаю через статическую переменную то разве флаг будет меняться у всех интересующих меня ресурсах?

Comment: Статика принадлежит классу, а не объекту
Попробуйте, поэкспериментируйте, - обязательно что-то получиться